# Can I get a list of points in a polygon using Quadtrees?

Tags: point-in-polygon, quadtree

I'm storing vertices in a PR (or PM if needed) quadtree and would like to be able to:

1. Find out if a given polygon contains at least one point
2. Optionally: Get a list of all the points within a given polygon

My questions:

1. Is a PR/PM QuadTree the right data structure for quickly getting a list of points within a polygon. Are there better suited structures?
2. What type of an algorithm would you use to extract points within a polygon from a QuadTree (or your suggested structure)? I don't need a coded solution, but just some algorithmic hints on how this can be achieved. It would also be helpful if there are any resources you could point me to.

Thanks, 
Nick